# How does the Apple store obfuscate its use of Canjs?

Tags: obfuscation, canjs

- If one goes to the Apple store using `Google Chrome` and does this [Click Here](http://i.ralph.io/wgdqqskx.png) , one can see that the Apple store uses the `Canjs javascript` MVC framework.
- However, in the `view source` of the Apple store page, I can't find any links to `Canjs` or any obvious obfuscations. Any idea how they obfuscate this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go [here](http://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4041/store.apple.com/rs-web/rel/base.js) you can see that Apple is simply storing all external js in one file. Probably to increate page load speed ([more info](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/service/CombineJavaScript)).